# Create document for codes with PhpDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc

I want create document for my codes with PhpDocumtor
but i don't know about PhpDocumtor requirements tags in PhpDoc
Which tags should be insert in my codes?
I used following tags:

```
@var
@return
```

Answer (score 1):

All docs about PhpDoc are here: http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html

The tags are on the left side.
An example use.

```
/**
 * Title text.
 * 
 * Description text.
 * 
 * @param string $arg Description.
 * @return array The description for return.
 */
function somefn($arg){
   return (array) $arg;
}
```